# Select drop-down scroll style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any **css** way to stylize the scroll of the default ***select*** drop-down? 
Or it`s better just forgot this and use *div*, *ul*, *li* and some ***javascript*** ?

```
<select id="selector">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Here is a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/33eLkLo1/), of overflown *select* and *div* nearby, where only div has applyed scroll style, as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrollbar CSS styles are not part of the W3C standard for CSS and therefore most browsers just ignore them. Some browser have a way to style this, but the javascript solution is the best for cross-browser.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for, but any way, at least you`ve confirmed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can forgot this beacause they look different in different bowsers and OS. You can use some JQuery plugin to replace system elements.

Check this : https://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements

Comment: the link is dated as 2009, that`s to old, but anyway thanks for respond.

Comment: Oh yes, but I hope this has helped you anyway.